# node.js setInterval not working in custom module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing a web application in node.js to collect data from devices on a network using snmp. This is my first real encounter with node.js and javascript. In the app each device will be manipulated through a module I named `SnmpMonitor.js`. This module will maintain basic device data as well as the snmp and database connection.

One of the features of the app is the ability to constantly monitor data from smart metering devices. To do this I created the following code to start and stop the monitoring of the device. It uses setInterval to constantly send a snmp get request to the device. Then the event listener picks it up and will add the collected data to a database. Right now the listener just prints to show it was successful.

```
var dataOIDs = ["1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0","1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0"];
var intervalDuration = 500;
var monitorIntervalID;
var dataCollectionEvent = "dataCollectionComplete";
var emitter = events.EventEmitter(); // Uses native Event Module

//...

function startMonitor(){
    if(monitorIntervalID !== undefined){
        console.log("Device monitor has already started");
    } else {
        monitorIntervalID = setInterval(getSnmp,intervalDuration,dataOIDs,dataCollectionEvent);
        emitter.on(dataCollectionEvent,dataCallback);
    }
 }

function dataCallback(recievedData){
    // receivedData is returned from getSnmp completion event
    // TODO put data in database
    console.log("Event happened");
}

function stopMonitor(){
    if(monitorIntervalID !== undefined){
        clearInterval(monitorIntervalID);
        emitter.removeListener(dataCollectionEvent,dataCallback);
    } else {
        console.log("Must start collecting data before it can be stopped");
    }
}

//...
```

I also have a test file, `test.js`, that requires the module, starts monitoring, waits 10 seconds, then stops it.

```
var test = require("./SnmpMonitor");

test.startMonitor();
setTimeout(test.stopMonitor,10000);
```

My problem is that the `setInterval` function in `startMonitor()` is not being run. I have tried placing `console.log("test");` before, inside, and after it to test it. The inside test output never executes. The `monitorIntervalID` variable is also returned as `undefined`. I have tested `setInterval(function(){ console.log("test"); },500);` in my test.js file and it runs fine with no issues. I feel like this is a noobie mistake but I just can't seem to figure out why it won't execute.

Here is a link to the entire module: [SnmpMonitor.js](https://gist.github.com/8bitAlex/62766360331f1922717a)

Comment: What is `emitter`? Is that defined in the scope? And where is the `getSnmp` function defined?

Comment: emitter = event.EventEmitter(), it is an EventEmitter() object. And getSnmp(OID,eventName) uses the net-snmp library as a get request. It takes OIDs in an array and an event name string to response with the results. When it receives results it emits the event with the data as a callback parameter. Ill update the code to more accurately reflect that.

Comment: The deleted answer that mentioned the fact that `setInterval()` only takes two arguments was right, as far as I know. What do you expect those other arguments to do?

Comment: @Pointy I thought the same but apparently you can do that to pass more arguments into the callback: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

Comment: @MattHarrison oh OK - it's not documented, but it does seem to work. (Note that he's using Node.js, not a browser.)

Comment: @Pointy `setInterval` accepting multiple works for node.js as well because node is built on top of V8 which is the javascript engine in chrome. There is feature parity for language usage between the two.

Comment: @tkone sure, but I still think that should be documented on the Node doc site :)

Comment: @Pointy it isn't part of node.  Node's documentation involves the modules it provides and the changes or additions it makes to the environment. `setInterval` is a language mechanic is part of V8 natively. Like the `JSON` object or any of the base object prototypes like `Array.prototype` or `Object.prototype`.  You don't see documentation for `Array.prototype.forEach` on node's website...

Comment: @tkone well, OK, but there *is* documentation for `setInterval` and `setTimeout` on the Node site, and it doesn't include this stuff. I can't see any reason for it to describe `setInterval` and *not* include information about the extra parameters, unless they explicitly intend to keep them undocumented because the V8 guys don't want to commit to long-term support.

Comment: How are you exporting your functions?

Comment: even if I change it to `setInterval(function(){console.log("test");});` it fails so the extra parameters are not the fail point, well most likely not. And I export them `exports.startMonitor = startMonitor;` `exports.stopMonitor = stopMonitor;`

Comment: No matter where I put `setInterval()` in the module it will not work. I tested it in my test file and it worked fine. I made a workaround by using setTimeout in a recursive function but I don't think this is the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

I not sure exactly what was wrong but I got it to work by overhauling the whole class/module. I thought the way I had it was going to allow me to create new monitors objects but I was wrong. Instead I created two functions inside the monitor file that do the same thing. I changed the start function to the following.

```
SnmpMonitor.prototype.start = function() {
    var snmpSession = new SNMP(this.deviceInfo.ipaddress,this.emitter);
    var oids = this.deviceInfo.oids;
    var emit = this.emitter;
    var duration = this.intervalDuration;

    this.intervalID = setInterval(function(){
        snmpSession.get(dataCollectionEvent,emit,oids);
    },duration);
};
```

The `setInterval` function seems to work best when the callback function is set inside an anonymous function, even though technically you can pass it directly. Using the `this.` notation I created some class/module/function variables (whatever its called in js) that are in scope of the whole class. For some reason the variables accessed through `this.` do not work so well when directly in a function or expression so I created temp variables for them. In my other version all the variables were global and js doesn't seem to like that.